# How to parse "<tag ... /><tag>...</tag>" with Regexp correctly?

Tags: javascript, regex

The content is something like this:

```
<style src="./x.css" /><style src="./z.css">cccccc</style>
```

I want to parse the full "style" tag out(not include the self closing tag), which should be:

```
<style src="./z.css">cccccc</style>
```

I tried this:

```
/(<style[^>]*>.*?<\/style>)/gi
```

But it matches the whole string, begin with the self closing tag. But I can't exclude the character "/" with [^>/]*, as "/" may appear in the attribute.

[@Jerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1578604/jerry) mentioned something like this(Thanks, Jerry):

```
/(<style[^>]*[^\/]>.*?<\/style>)/gi
```

But it will fails for:

```
<style src="./x.css" /><style>cccccc</style>
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/Wq7nE/2/).

Comment: Use a DOM parser, not regexp.

Comment: What's wrong with your regex is that `.*?` allows `<` and `>` to pass. You might try to use `[^<]*` instead of `.*?`. All the same, a proper html parser is more appropriate.

Comment: Dom parser is a little heavy for me, as I don't need the tree structure, only some tags.

Comment: @Jerry, .*? doesn't matter here, I think the key part to improve is [^>]*,  make it include "/", but not endsWith "/"

Comment: @Andrew If you are so sure about that, you can certainly add `[^/]` at the end like that: `(<style[^>]*[^\/]>.*?<\/style>)`

Comment: If I answer with a regex solution, I get downvoted. So I leave it in the comments `/<(?:(?!\/>).)+?>.*?<\/[^>]*>/g`. [**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/rE2hO7)

Comment: @Jerry, that's do work for my example, but it will fail for something like <style>..</style>

Comment: @Adrew HamZa's regex would've been my next try.

Comment: @Jerry I forgot to use a backreferece to match the same tags, you could do it, right :) ?

Comment: Thanks, @HamZa. But would you please add the tag backreferece for me, I can't figure out how?

Comment: @HamZa Well, I guess so... `(<(\S+)(?:(?!\/).|"[^"]*")*>.*?<\/\2>)` That should take care of the `/` in quotes as well.

Comment: @Andrew A [quick fiddle](http://regex101.com/r/mO7tD2) `/<((?:(?!\/>)\S)+)(?:(?!\/>)[\s\S])*?>[\s\S]*?<\/\1\s*>/g`. If you ever want to parse html with regex, try to reach me in the [regex chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex)

Comment: @HamZa, would you copy your comment as an answer, and I'll make it the accepted one.